# Two easy questions for arithmetic progression

Tags: linear-algebra

I was not able to solve either of these, I kept hitting many mistakes and it would be much appreciated if the solution to these two could be provided, thanks a lot in advance.

If the sum of all the terms of an arithmetic progression $1,4,7,\ldots, x$ is $187$ then find $x$.

The sum of the first $3$ terms of an arithmetic progression is $33$. If the product of the first and the third exceeds the second by $29$, find the the progression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_1=1,d=3,a_n=x=a_1+(n-1)d=1+(n-1)3=3n-2$$
$$S_n=n/2(a_1+a_n)=n/2(3n-1)=187$$
$$3n^2-n-374=0$$
$$n_{1}=-11,n_{2}=34/3$$
because $n$ is natural $x$ must be natural so series that fulfill your equation does not exists 
$$S_{11}=11/2\cdot 32=176< 187< S_{12}=12/2\cdot 35=210$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

The nth term of your AP Series is $a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d$ , where $a_1$ is the initial member and d the difference between successive members

For your First Question

$$a_1 = 1; d = a_2 - a_1 = 4 - 1 = 3$$
$$a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d = 1 + 3(n-1)= 3\cdot n - 2$$
$$S = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 .... a_n = 187$$

For your second question

$$a_1 = a;a_2 = a + (2-1)d = a+d;a_3 = a + (3-1)d = a + 2d$$
$$a_1 +a_2+a_3  = 33\tag1$$
$$a_1 \cdot a_3 = a_2 + 29\tag2$$
Now solve the equations

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The $n$-th term in the first arithmetic progression is of the form $1+3n$.

Answer (score 0):

The second question is simply 2 equations and 2 unknowns:

$$ 3 a+ 3 d =33$$

$$a (a + 2 d) = a+d+29$$

where $a$ is the first term and $d$ is the difference between terms.

Comment: Hey it's $3a+3d=33$

Comment: Yes, my  mistake.  Thanks.  In the future, though, allow the poster of the answer to make the correction.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question. 
choose 1st term=$n-d$; 2nd term=$n$; third term=$n+d$ 
where $d$ is the common difference of the A.P.

Adding the three terms you get $n=33/3=11$.

now subtracting the second term from the product of the first and second term we get 
$\{(n-d)*(n+d)\} - n = 29$ 
,i.e., $(n^2 - d^2) - n = 29 $

Substitute $n=11$ to get $(121 - d^2) - 11 = 29$.
therefore $d= 9$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ), I updated your posting as an example. Regards